# Linear regression with High Dimensional dataset is slow

Tags: performance, linear-regression, dimensions, least-squares

I am looking for a regression model that's very efficient with a large number of features.

Well, basically I am using OLS model with a dataset that has around 600 features. And I noticed that it's very slow.

Could you kindly suggest other models that can be effective and efficiently more than OLS with high dimensional datasets?

Comment: About how many observations do you have?

Comment: I have around 12 observations .. very small number compared to the number of features